What is the source that the Shacharit Chazan starts Hamelech from its place and then goes to the prayer post?
What is the source for the practice of the Shacharit Chazan (Ashkenazi, Nusach Sfard) beginning the Hamelech prayer from its original place and then moving to the prayer stand?
